# В Phpstorm есть ли навигационное окно

Tags: phpstorm

Подскажите, есть ли в phpstorm навигатор по файлам, как в netbeans? Например, какие классы и методы используют данный файл и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос немного непонятен: нужно просмотреть классы и методы, имеющиеся в данном файле, или просмотреть список файлов, где используются классы и методы из данного файла.

**Для просмотра классов, полей и методов, используемых в данном файле, следует выбрать файл на вкладке Project и нажать на вкладку Structure.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Для просмотра файлов, в которых используется данный класс/метод/поле, следует нажать на нём <kbd>ПКМ</kbd> и выбрать пункт Find Usages. Результаты поиска отобразятся внизу.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Вы удовлетворили меня полностью своим ответом)))